# To hit one's leg on the ground as to scare a rat?

Tags: word-choice

I have the following options in mind:

- `stamp` the foot on the ground
- `hit` the foot on the ground
- `bang` the foot on the ground
- `stomp` the foot on the ground

which of these is "most correct"?

The context:

My character is looking at this huge rat that's fearlessly gnawing at his fruit lying on the ground. He wants to scare it off, so he does this act with his right foot...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are my feelings on this usage question: Stamp and stomp are the only two choices that have a literary feel to them. However, stamping one's foot is usually the result of frustration, where stomping is more what one would do to scare off a rat.

Comment: I'd venture to suggest that *stomp* is a more American term; *stamp* would be more common in British English.

Comment: @CharlE, you know, it is in British English novels that I first encountered girls stamping their feet in pretty buttoned boots.  In American English, it was only horses that stamped their hooves, while people stomped around, stomped off in anger and stomped on spiders.

Comment: Lucky you. Pretty boots are always pretty boots.But are you disagreeing with me or not?

Comment: @CharlE, maybe something was lost in the tonelessness of forum commenting, but I was agreeing with you.

Comment: no offence intended! Hope none taken; if indeed, apologies.